# Link buttons on the Flash movie not working on Fire Fox/Chrome

Tags: flash

I have a flash banner that rotate 6 images(slides). and it includes 6 buttons to navigate in to each image. Also images are rotates automatically every 10sec.

But these buttons are not clickable in FF/Chrome, but work fine in IE with wmode: transparent. Also these buttons work fine in all browsers with wmode: opaque.
Also there is drop down menu on top of the flash movie(a separate menu not included in the flash). In wmode: opaque dropdown part of the menu goes behind the Flash. In wmode: transparent that want happen.

Please help some one!!

Thank You All

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer
use `wmode=window`


long answer
Anything other then wmode= window will have some very unexpected results and have been know to cause flash to run slower and a whole world of other issues.

A banner shouldn't be opaque or transparent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to second @The_asMan for the following reasons:

1) I would have said that say that.
2) I believe he may be quoting Seinfeld when Kramer picks up his license plates.

Also, if you aren't using **swfObject**, you should check it out. **swfObject** will handle alot of the **delicate cross-domain issues** most people forget. However, you still have to **add wmode:transparent** to fix things like other elements (menus) going behind flash. You can check it out at the [SWFObject Project Home](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).